# is there a jquery one liner code for toggling ENABLED checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Is there a jquery method/whatever to toggle all checkboxes EXCEPT disabled ones? i have this code right now:

```
$('.select-all-categories').toggle(function() {
  $('#test-categories input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked", false);
  return false;
}, function() { 
  $('#test-categories input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked", true);
  return false;
});
```

and it works fine(selects/deselects all checkboxes). BUt some of the checkboxes are disabled and I would like it to NOT be affected by the toggle. Is there a way to do this WITHOUT doing a for each and looping through all and checking if they are disabled or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`:enabled`](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector) to only select checkboxes that are enabled:

```
$('#test-categories input[type="checkbox"]:enabled')
```

By the way, you can replace `[type="checkbox"]` with [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector):

```
$('#test-categories input:checkbox:enabled')
```